# Ghostscript exports PNG but cuts half of the landscape page

Tags: c#, pdf, ghostscript, ghostscript.net, ghostscriptsharp

I am trying to convert pdf to picture with Ghostscript. I have a landscape A3 PDF but no matter what I do, I only get the left half of every page.. I tried adding the `-dPDFFitPage`, `-dFIXEDMEDIA`, and other parameters but it didn’t seem to change anything..

My code without additional customswitches (C#):

```
var r=new GhotsScriptRasterizer();
r.open(pdfPath);
var pdf2png=r.GetPage(300,300,1);
pdf2png.Save(savePath);
```

I am using Ghostscript 8.64 32bit.

Comment: You're going to have to share the PDF, nobody can say much without looking at it. You also haven't said which version of Ghostscript you are using, or supplied a command line. I notice that you aren't using Ghostscript directly but using some kind of wrapper. You should probably move the tag to ghostscriptsharp or ghostscript.net (depending which one you are using) rather than Ghostscript.

Comment: Well the first thing you should do is use a more recent version, 8.64 is 10 years old! The current version is 9.27 and 9.28 will be released shortly (currently at release candidate 4). You also still haven't supplied a PDF file or a command line (or a complete list of arguments, since you aren't using Ghostscript itself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. It was really the version - GS 9.26 32Bit worked for me. Thanks!